# Geocoding displaying "ZERO_RESULTS" to every input

Tags: javascript, php, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

A form in an html file passes an input called "address" to a php file "registerEvent.php" where it is to be geocoded. No matter what address is inputted, the function still outputs ZERO_RESULTS status in an alert which can happen if the inputted address is invalid(i.e. NULL or an impossible address). I have tested, that recieving the address value from the html form works correctly both in php and at the start of the codeAddress() function.

```
    <?php 
$geoadrese = $_POST['address'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var inputLat;
var inputLng;
function codeAddress() {
  var address = '<?php echo $geoadrese; ?>';

// everything works fine up until this point
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    inputLat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    inputLng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    window.location.href = "registerEvent.php?inputLat=" + inputLat + "&inputLng=" + inputLng;
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    };

  });
    }
    codeAddress();
</script>
```